# How to use NSWindowOcclusionState.Visible in Swift

Tags: macos, swift, appkit

I am trying to implement window toggling (something I've done many times in Objective-C), but now in Swift. It seams that I am getting the use of NSWindowOcclusionState.Visible incorrectly, but I really cannot see my problem. Only the line w.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self) is called after the initial window creation.

Any suggestions?

```
var fileArchiveListWindow: NSWindow? = nil

@IBAction func tougleFileArchiveList(sender: NSMenuItem) {
    if let w = fileArchiveListWindow {
        if w.occlusionState == NSWindowOcclusionState.Visible {
            w.orderOut(self)
        }
        else {
            w.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
        }
    }
    else {
        let sb = NSStoryboard(name: "FileArchiveOverview",bundle: nil)
        let controller: FileArchiveOverviewWindowController = sb?.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("FileArchiveOverviewController") as FileArchiveOverviewWindowController
        fileArchiveListWindow = controller.window
        fileArchiveListWindow?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but I just run into the same problem. Checking the `occlusionState` is done a bit differently in Swift using the `AND` binary operator:

```
if (window.occlusionState & NSWindowOcclusionState.Visible != nil) {
    // visible
}
else {
    // not visible
}
```

Comment: In Swift 2 I am getting: Could not find an overload for '&' that accepts the supplied arguments

Answer (score 2):

In recent SDKs, the `NSWindowOcclusionState` bitmask is imported into Swift as an `OptionSet`. You can use `window.occlusionState.contains(.visible)` to check if a window is visible or not (fully occluded).

Example:

```
observerToken = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSWindow.didChangeOcclusionStateNotification, object: window, queue: nil) { note in
    let window = note.object as! NSWindow
    if window.occlusionState.contains(.visible) {
        // window at least partially visible, resume power-hungry calculations
    } else {
        // window completely occluded, throttle down timers, CPU, etc.
    }
}
```